# Can all quasiconvex functions be represented as a ratio of a convex function and a concave function?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

My optimization algorithms teacher raised this conjecture:

$\forall f:D\subset\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ quasiconvex $\exists (p, q)$ where

$p:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ convex,

$q:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ concave with $q(x)>0~\forall x\in D$

such that

$$f(x) = \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$$

Comment: Seems doubtful to me. Quasiconvex functions can be discontinuous, and convex/concave functions cannot. As a concrete example,$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $x \neq 0$} \\ 0 & \text{if $x = 0$}\end{cases}$$would have to have $p(x) = q(x)$ for $x \neq 0$, which would imply $p(0) = q(0)$, by continuity, contradicting $p(0)/q(0) = f(0) = 0$. If you are thinking of insisting on $f$ being continuous, you might want to consider also the possibility of $q(x) = 0$ for certain $x$. Do you want to disallow it (and force $q(x) < 0$ for all $x$)? Or exclude/limit the zeros of $q$?

Comment: One of the conditions thought about was q(x)<0, I forgot about that.

Comment: You'd really need $f$ to be non-positive. If $f$ were non-negative and $q(x) < 0$, then $p(x) \le 0$. But no non-constant convex function is bounded above.